# Chrome Webstore inline installation with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, chrome-web-store

I'm a newbie with AngularJS and trying to install a Chrome extension following the [Webstore inline installation guide](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation)

In my .html file

```
<button data-ng-click="chromeExtensionInstall()" id="install-button">Add to Chrome</button>
```

In my .js file

```
function successCallback () {
    window.alert('success');
}

function failureCallback () {
    window.alert('failure');
}

$scope.chromeExtensionInstall = function() {
    if (!chrome.app.isInstalled) {
        chrome.webstore.install('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/...',
            successCallback(), failureCallback());
    }
};
```

Both alerts are displayed and then getting this Uncaught Exception: "Chrome Web Store installations can only be initiated by a user gesture"

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chrome.webstore.install` function accept 2 callback parameters, which means 2 pointers to function. You should not call those functions yourself, but just pass in their names, like this:

```
chrome.webstore.install('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/...',
        successCallback, failureCallback);
```

Instead of this:

```
chrome.webstore.install('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/...',
        successCallback(), failureCallback());
```

Do you see the difference ? If you don't, have a look on [this page](http://tobyho.com/2011/10/26/js-premature-invocation/) which explains it well (and there's also [this on 7 common JavaScript mistakes](http://tobyho.com/2011/11/16/7-common-js-mistakes-or-confusions/))

Comment: Thanks! It fixed the alerts bug but still getting the same Exception.

Comment: It may be an AngularJS related issue. Try this with plain old JavaScript code: `var button = document.getElementById('install-button'); button.addEventListener('click', chromeExtensionInstall, false);` (and declare your `chromeExtensionInstall` into the `window` scope too)

Comment: I found out I was debugging wrongly, because I was stepping through in the debugger, the install call was too late...

Comment: @pomeh: its not working i just tested in Google Chrome stable which is version 41 and also not working in Google Canary verison 43x. Please update your answer kindly. its misleading not working yet.

Answer (score 0):

Inline installation is composed of two parts:

1. A declarative  tag (like `<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/itemID">`) and
2. A call to the JavaScript function chrome.webstore.install(). In addition, you must also verify an association between the site that triggers inline installation and the relevant item(s) in the Chrome Web Store.

I think you are doing only the 2nd part. This link is helpful.

http://noelarlante.com/setup-chrome-extension-for-inline-installation/