# event trigger on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, coffeescript

I want to perform javascript validation after user submits the form. Documentation for jQuery `.submit()` clearly says:

> The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to submit a form.

But if I put

```
$('form.simple_form.new-channel').submit perform_validation()
```

into my code, `perform_validation()` is triggered every time page is rendered! Even when there is no form on it and no 'submit' button. What is the correct way to call a function after submitting a form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe You dont want to trigger action after submitting, You just want to run it after user clicks submit button.

Wouldn`t it work put like that?

```
$('form.simple_form.new-channel').submit(function(e){
  if(!perform_validation()){
    e.preventDefault(); //prevents form from being submitted if validation fails
    return;  //exits function
  }
})
```

Your perform_validation function should then return Boolean value.

EDIT:

You wrote Your function like this:

```
$('form.simple_form.new-channel').submit perform_validation()
```

which is exact the same as writing:

```
$('form.simple_form.new-channel').submit;
perform_validation();
```

In Your version script just runs the perform_validation() because it isn`t inside event handler.

You could also do it this way:

```
$('form.simple_form.new-channel').submit(perform_validation);
```

This one tells the script to run on the form submit, the function which name is passed as an argument.

Comment: so what is the difference between you answer and the code in ym question?

Comment: How do You understand the difference in this context?
$('form.simple_form.new-channel').submit just retrieves submit function code of form.simple_form.new-channel.
perform_validation() as You've written it runs this function.
The way You wrote it means just like this one:
$('form.simple_form.new-channel').submit; perform_validation();

Comment: @Leo have a look to this to see the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25179299/827168

Comment: @pomeh Answer You`ve attached isn`t truly relevant here.

Comment: great, i understand now what you meant and it works, i will accept your answer in a minute!

Comment: @entio yes it is, it's the exact same problem: the `perform_validation`is called too early. My answer also link to this web page "Premature Invocation": http://tobyho.com/2011/10/26/js-premature-invocation/

Comment: @pomeh Haven't dig deep enough. This site explains the problem very well. Sorry!

Comment: @entio no problem :) Your edit make this "common mistake" appears more clearly now, that's nice :)

Comment: @pomeh, maaan, You`ve reminded me :) I even was on this particular site once when I was beginning my scripting adventure! :D

Answer (score -2):

The problem is your syntax.

```
$('form.simple_form.new-channel').submit perform_validation()
```

Because of javascript's liberality the fact that you are not invoking submit here and you have no semicolin after perform_validation... causes no error, but simply invokes perform validation as if it was on the line all by its self with a semicolin.

to correct this, do this

```
$('form.simple_form.new-channel').submit(perform_validation);
```

Comment: You've just made the same mistake; premature invocation.
Read this one: http://tobyho.com/2011/10/26/js-premature-invocation/

Comment: @entio is right. Both lines are equivalent, but the first one `$('form.simple_form.new-channel').submit perform_validation()` is just CoffeScript code where parenthesis are not required around the `submit` method

Comment: @DaleCorns you can down vote them only if they don't answer to the OP question, which is indeed what you're answer is not doing. You could edit and correct your answer and then I could remove my downvote, but since there is already an accepted answer that make no sense at all.