# Chrome extension: Using Inline Installation does not give success/failure callbacks

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am able to install my chrome extension using 'Inline Installation method', from my webpage. But I am not getting any success/ failure callbacks.
My page has link to the extension in the head section of the page and the code as follows

```
  chrome.webstore.install('url to my extension', function () {
        //  Success!
        console.log('success!');
    }, function (err) {
        //  Error :(
        console.log('failed!');
    });
```

Comment: `chrome.webstore.install` function accepts 2 callback parameters, which means 2 pointers to function. You should not call those functions yourself, but just pass in their names. Probably duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178768/chrome-webstore-inline-installation-with-angularjs

Comment: @gui47 the callback functions are just getting defined, they are not getting called like in the link you list.